# Автоматическое создание картинок-миниатюр в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Как автоматически создать миниатюру (без нажатия на кнопку **"Задать миниатюру"**) в **WordPress** из первого изображения поста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Миниатюры в WordPress создаются без плагинов – в настройка указываются размеры миниатюр.

Если нужны другие генерируемые размеры – [add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).

Если же речь об изображении записи (Featured Image) – [Post  Thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post%20Thumbnails)

Answer (score 0):

В файле темы **functions.php** добавьте код:

```
// Включение поддержки миниатюр темой
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

После этого на странице создания нового поста появится блок справа **"Миниатюра записи"**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для вывода миниатюры, добавьте код в файл **single.php** вашей темы:

```
// Проверка на существование миниатюры
if(has_post_thumbnail())
{
    //Вывод миниатюры
     the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

Ссылки на документацию:

[add_theme_support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post%20Thumbnails)

[has_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/)

[the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)

Comment: Мне нужно автоматическое создание миниатюр.

Comment: Это и есть автоматическое создание миниатюр. Обрисуйте цель задачи, может неверно вас понимаю.

Comment: дело в том, что я не хочу нажимать по кнопке "Задать миниатюру".

Comment: Тогда это не "создание", а "присваивание". Совершено другой вопрос.

Comment: @D. Lomov в в новом переводе это звучит как "изображение записи". См https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0/

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы не задавать каждый раз миниатюру и выводить первое изображение поста, нужно написать такую функцию:

```
function first_img(){
    global $post;preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',$post->post_content,$img);
    return $img['1'];
}
```

И выводить ее значение вот так:

```
<?php $img=first_img();echo $img?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы на основе первого изображения поста генерировать миниатюры разного размера, пишем следующую функцию:

```
function aq_resize($url,$width,$height=null,$crop=null,$single=true){
    $up_info=wp_upload_dir();
    $up_dir=$up_info['basedir'];
    $up_url=$up_info['baseurl'];
    if (strpos($url,home_url()) === false){return false;}
    $rel_path = str_replace( $up_url, '', $url);
    $img_path = $up_dir . $rel_path;
    if (!file_exists($img_path) OR ! getimagesize($img_path)){return false;}
    $info = pathinfo($img_path);
    $ext = $info['extension'];
    list($orig_w,$orig_h) = getimagesize($img_path);
    $dims = image_resize_dimensions($orig_w, $orig_h, $width, $height, $crop);
    $dst_w = $dims['4'];
    $dst_h = $dims['5'];
    $suffix="{$dst_w}x{$dst_h}";
    $dstrel=str_replace('.'.$ext,'',$rel_path);
    $dest="{$up_dir}{$dstrel}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
    if($width >= $orig_w) {
        if(!$dst_h) :
            $img_url=$url;
            $dst_w=$orig_w;
            $dst_h=$orig_h;

        else :
            if(file_exists($dest) && getimagesize($dest)) {
                $img_url="{$up_url}{$dstrel}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
            }
            else {
                $resized=resize_image($img_path,$width,$height,$crop);
                $resized_rel=str_replace($up_dir,'',$resized);
                $img_url=$up_url.$resized_rel;
            }
        endif;
    }
    elseif(file_exists($dest) && getimagesize($dest)) {
        $img_url="{$up_url}{$dstrel}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
    }
    else {
        $resized=resize_image($img_path,$width,$height,$crop);
        $resized_rel=str_replace($up_dir,'',$resized);
        $img_url=$up_url.$resized_rel;
    }

    if($single) {
        $image = $img_url;
    } else {
        $image = array (
            0 => $img_url,
            1 => $dst_w,
            2 => $dst_h
        );
    }
    return $image;
}
```

А в месте, где необходимо вывести миниатюру с определенным размером, вызываем следующую функцию:

```
<?php echo aq_resize(first_img(),180,130,true)?>
```