# Разделение блоков на несколько колонок

Tags: html, css, css3

Расположил блоки в две колонки, но последний если последний блок в текущей колонке не помещается, то он частично переносится в новую, как сделать, чтобы блоки переносились целиком, не резались на 2 колонки?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно привести код в тексте вопроса, а скриншоты использовать только в качестве дополнения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно реализовать с помощью `flexbox`:

```css
.column {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.column-block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="column-block">Блок 1</div>
  <div class="column-block">Блок 2</div>
  <div class="column-block">Блок 3</div>
  <div class="column-block">Блок 4</div>
  <div class="column-block">Блок 5</div>
  <div class="column-block">Блок 6</div>
  <div class="column-block">Блок 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: не стыдно копировать чужие ответы?

Comment: @Vadizar, эмм... и чей я ответ скопировал?

Comment: вместо того, чтобы пометить сообщение как дубликат, вы переносите ответы с этого вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619955/Разделение-списка-на-несколько-колонок/619962#619962

Comment: @Vadizar, 1) я ваших ответов и не читал никогда. 2) Мне нечего делать и по каждому вопросу искать дубликат и ответы копировать?

Comment: видимо так и есть.

Comment: @Vadizar, этот метод настолько редкий, что прям никто о таком переносе не знает

Comment: проехали. Но в любом случае, данный вопрос поднимается уже не один раз и его стоит заминусовать.

Comment: @Vadizar, не думаю. Зачем минусовать пользователя? Понимаете, что даже при полном желании, можно не найти такой же вопрос и задать его снова. В таких ситуациях и существует "Закрыть, как дубликат" и не надо минусить невинного пользователя

Comment: Ну меня почему-то начали минусовать за не очевидный. дубликат и пометили как дубликат. А здесь явный дубликат. Так почему стоит относиться неравно к пользователям?

Comment: @Vadizar, минусят за состав вопроса (нечёткий, непонятна суть, абсурдный вопрос). За минус не за что могут давать бан

Comment: Ну понятно. Как всегда.

Comment: @Vadizar, если вас заминусили не за что, то обратитесь к модераторам, что бы они оценили ситуацию и исправили несправедливость

Comment: к примеру, зачем было минусовать и закрывать этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619566/Автоматическое-создание-картинок-миниатюр-в-wordpress-без-плагина, а этот, который явный дубликат, оставлять?

Comment: @Vadizar, у вас не очень понятная суть вопроса. Изложите более конкретно проблему. Этот не оставляют. Уже 2 голоса за закрытие. Осталось 3

Comment: исправил только что.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53376/discussion-between-yuri-and-vadizar).